# How to make sure certain elements not get into arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array lets say

```
array1 = ["abc", "a", "wxyz", "ab",......]
```

How do I make sure neither for example "a" (any 1 character), "ab" (any 2 characters), "abc" (any 3 characters), nor words like "that", "this", "what" etc nor any of the foul words are saved in `array1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This removes elements with less than 4 characters and words like this, that, what from `array1` (if I got it right):

```
array1.reject! do |el|
    el.length < 4 || ['this', 'that', 'what'].include?(el)
end
```

This changes `array1`. If you use `reject` (without `!`), it'll return the result and not change `array1`

Answer (score 1):

You can open and add a new interface to the Array class which will disallow certain words. Example:

```
class Array
  def add(ele)
    unless rejects.include?(ele)
      self.push ele
    end
  end

  def rejects
    ['this', 'that', 'what']  
  end
end

arr = []

arr.add "one"
puts arr

arr.add "this"
puts arr

arr.add "aslam"
puts arr
```

Output would be:

> one one one aslam

And notice the word "this" was not added.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stop list. Using a hash for this would be more efficient than an array as lookup time will be consistant with a hash. With an array the lookup time is proportional to the number of elements in the array. If you are going to check for stop words a lot, I suggest using a hash that contains all the stop words. Using your code, you could do the following

```
badwords_a = ["abc", "a", "wxyz", "ab"] # Your array of bad words
badwords_h = {}                         # Initialize and empty hash
badwords_a.each{|word| badwords_h[word] = nil}  # Fill the hash

goodwords = [] 

words_to_process = ["abc","a","Foo","Bar"] # a list of words you want to process

words_to_process.each do |word| # Process new words
 if badwords_h.key?(word)
 else
 goodwords << word  # Add the word if it did not match the bad list
 end
end

puts goodwords.join(", ")
```